# javascript accessing object

Tags: javascript

consider the following code:

```
 <script>
  person={
          firstname:"John",
          lastname:function(){alert(this.firstname)}
         }
          person.lastname();
 </script>
```

like local variables can be accessed from anywhere within the function ,to access the property of an object why should we use **this**  keyword?Since we are within the object is the use of **this** keyword compulsory?

Comment: Yes, unless you want to use person.firstname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in JavaScript, when you use `firstname`, interpreter is looking for that variable in the current scope and, later, in all parent scopes. But objects are not forming scopes.

Because of that, you need to access `firstname` via a special variable - `this`.

**Hint:** functions are creating scopes, so on example:

```
 var person = function () {
     var firstname = "John";

     return {
         lastname: function () {
             alert(firstname)
         }
     };
 }();
```

would work without `this`.

Answer (score 2):

`this` keyword in JavaScript is a somehow different compared to other languages. The object bound to `this` in the current scope is determined by how the current function was called, it can't be set by assignment during execution, and it can be different each time the function is called!

```
var person1 = {
    firstname: "John",
    lastname: function () { alert(this.firstname) }
}

var person2 = {
    firstname: "James",
}
person2.lastname = person1.lastname.bind(person2);

var firstname = "Rick";
```

Simple call:

```
person1.lastname();  // "John"
```

Context change call:

```
person1.lastname.call(window);  // "Rick"
```

Bound Function call:

```
person2.lastname();  // "James"
```

`this` also behaves differently on the `prototype chain` or in `DOM event handlers`